How to write one-element row in 2 by 2 smallmatrix?
The following code
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&a\\p&q\end{smallmatrix}\right]

gives 2 by 2 matrix where the first row is a a  and the second row is p q.
How to have only a in the first row and how to have it in the middle of the row?
Thank you,

You can insert the a midway between p and q using some box manipulation in the first row. For this you'll mark the left- and right-most positions of the second row, and use these x-coordinates to place the first row.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}

\begin{document}

\[
  % Original layout
  \left[
    \begin{smallmatrix}
      a & a \\ 
      p & q
    \end{smallmatrix}
  \right]
  \qquad
  % Measured layout
  \bigl[
    \begin{smallmatrix}
      \makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[\dimexpr\zposx{right}sp-\zposx{left}sp]{$\scriptstyle a$}}
        \phantom{p} \\
     \zsaveposx{left}p & q\zsavepos{right} % Capture outer-most x-coordinates
    \end{smallmatrix}
  \bigr]
  \qquad
  % Faked layout
  \bigl[
    \begin{smallmatrix}
      \makebox[1em]{$\scriptstyle a$}    \\
      \makebox[1em]{$\scriptstyle p ~ q$}
    \end{smallmatrix}
  \bigr]
\]

\end{document}

Position/coordinate marking is achieved using the savepos module from zref. x-coordinates are retrieved using \zposx{<label>} in small points. So, the width of a box that is exactly the same as the second row elements is \dimexpr\zposx{right}sp-\zposx{left}sp. \phantom{p} just positions the box at the correct location.
Since the position storage uses the .aux file (like traditional \label-\refs), you'll have to compile at least twice with every change in the position of the matrix to allow for the references to settle (also for the first compilation).
The third matrix was created with just two rows containing a faked array. Visually, the end user may not notice the difference.

thank you much appreciated

Unfortunately smallmatrix doesn't support \multicolumn cells. So, you need to define a new environment, which mimic smallmatrix size and enable to use \multicolumn instruction. Something like this:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newenvironment{bsmallarray}
{\setlength\arraycolsep{1.2pt}\scriptsize\linespread{0.66}\selectfont
 \begin{bmatrix}
}{
 \end{bmatrix}
 }
 
\begin{document}

small matrix: $\begin{bsmallmatrix} a&a\\ p&q \end{bsmallmatrix}$,
small array:  $\begin{bsmallarray} \multicolumn{2}{c}{a}\\ p&q \end{bsmallarray}$

\end{document}



thank you for the nice answer
